# WebGrid Alignment in MVC3 with RAZOR

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid, razor-grid

I want to set different - different width and alignment in all the columns in WEBGRID in MVC 3. It means that In the above code I have 5 columns now I want to set different alignment and width of all the headers.

**Below is my code :**

```
@{WebGrid grid = new WebGrid();
  if (@Model.VendorItemsList != null)
  {
      grid = new WebGrid(source: @Model.VendorItemsList, ajaxUpdateContainerId:         "gridSearch", canSort: true, rowsPerPage: Model.PageSize);
  }
}
<div id="gridSearch" class="tableGrid">
    @{            
        @grid.GetHtml(
            mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
            columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("VendorItemName", header: @GeneralResource.Vendor + " " + @GeneralResource.Item + " " + @GeneralResource.Name),
            grid.Column("ItemName", header: @GeneralResource.Item),
            grid.Column("ItemCategoryName", header: @GeneralResource.Category),
            grid.Column("VendorName", header: @GeneralResource.Vendor)
            ))
        }
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there isn't a built-in way to control the widths, you'll have to use CSS styling.  First give classes to the header and body rows:

```
@grid.GetHtml(
    headerStyle: "header_row", 
    rowStyle: "item_row"
    // ...
)
```

Then style them using the nth-child pseudo-class selectors, eg:

```
tr.header_row th:nth-child(1) { width: 100px; }
tr.header_row th:nth-child(2) { width: 75px; }
tr.header_row th:nth-child(3) { width: 50px; }

tr.item_row td:nth-child(1) { width: 100px; }
tr.item_row td:nth-child(2) { width: 75px; }
tr.item_row td:nth-child(3) { width: 50px; }
```

Comment: @dbasemen This worked perfectly for setting the borders of cells.  Couldn't get it to work for width though.

Comment: The width setting does work for columns but it is affected by the webgrid width and the browser window size.